# Issue with changing codeshare flight

Tags: air-travel, code-share

So, I have a flight that I booked through American, but is operated by Alaska. I'm now looking to change it (ideally through Alaska, as the flight is 62 days from now and they apparently don't charge a change fee outside 60 days). However, Alaska seems to only allow changes for flights booked through them, while American only allows changes for flights on their own planes.

My question is, is it possible to get this changed, and if so, which airline should I call to change it?

Answer (score 2):

The only airline that can change the ticket is the one that the ticket stock is on. Since you booked with American, you will have a ticket starting 001. Since it's not Alaska's ticket, Alaska cannot change it until the flight comes under airport control at check-in time.

You can only call AA to change the ticket.